# Tray icon utility to track WAN IP address

Tags: windows, internet, ip-address

I need small tray icon utility for windows which will track my internet (wan) ip address changes. I guess there should some freeware but I couldn't find any.

Comment: I want the same but for private IP and I want to choose the interface and it should show ip when I hover mouse over the taskbar icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of these two, this is an open source project called ip monitor, it does exactly what you ask for http://sourceforge.net/projects/ipmonitor/

There is another here called Mywanip which is free, but is a cut down version of a commercial product by the look of it, but still does what you ask for.

http://download.cnet.com/MyWanIp/3000-2155_4-10194789.html

Comment: Thanks, both of them are nice. That is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

There is an app in the Microsoft Store called [IpTray](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/iptray/9n3pbc9fj1n1) that as of this writing costs $3.89 (NON-REFUNDABLE) and can be installed on up to ten Windows 10 devices.

In the app overview, it claims "Better readability" although, as you can see from the overview's screenshot, it's still not as legible as the system clock time.  The app has the following permissions

- Access all your files, peripheral devices, apps, programs and
  registry
- Access your Internet connection

When I first installed it, it displayed only one segment of my WAN IP, and even then, only intermittently.  I had to right-click on the system tray, select `Taskbar settings`, scroll down and select `Select which icons appear on the taskbar` and then scroll down and turn the slider for the ambiguously-named `SystrayComponent` to On.  Each segment of the IP is in its own icon, and you can drag them around so that they are not in the correct order, but after a few seconds they will move back to the correct order.  Finally, you can right-click on the icons to get About or Exit, but not a way to copy the IP to the clipboard.  Given my experience and the lack of documentation, I rated the app only two stars.  Hopefully the author will improve it in the near future :-/

Comment: I just discovered that it doesn't handle IPv6 addresses very well either - everything is crammed (and clipped) into one icon, and the other three go to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an opensource script that shows your location IP address, country flag, and country ISO code: https://github.com/icamys/locindicator

Looks like that:

[image: location country flag, ISO code, and IP address]

Comment: Nice, but op is looking for Windows tool